# Javascript - Help to update the display of my calculator to display the number of the button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, addeventlistener

I'm building a calculator using HTML, CSS, and Javascript as a project. I have the HTML and CSS pretty much set - I'm having trouble coding the javascript so that I can interact with the HTML elements. I added event listeners to my number buttons - and on click I want them to update the text on the display. I can't quite figure out the correct method of doing this after researching for quite a while.

I've tried variations of updating the display through with eventListeners on my buttons and whichever number is pressed the display.textContent = button.innerText. But this doesn't update the integer on the display. Any help in the right direction would be helpful! thank you!

The HTML is below and the javascript is below that.

```
<body>
    <div class = 'calculator-grid'>
        <div class = 'output'>
            <div class = 'previous-operand'></div>
            <div data-display class = 'display'></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear class = 'span-two grey-button'>AC</button>
        <button data-delete class = 'grey-button'>DEL</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>÷</button>
        <button data-number >7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>*</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>+</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>-</button>
        <button data-number class = 'span-two'>0</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-equals class = 'orange-button'>=</button>
    </div>
```

```
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operator]');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const equalButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const display = document.querySelector('[data-display]');

function updateDisplay() {

}

function clear() {
    display.textContent = '';
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clear();
})


numberButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click',() => {
    let buttonContent = button.innerText;
    display.textContent = buttonContent;
}))
```

And here are my computing function which I'm going to call against the numbers I press.

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function multiply(a , b) {
    return a * b;
}

function divide(a, b) {
    return a / b;
}

function operate(firstNum, secondNum, operator) {
    let result = 0;
    let operationResult;
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            operationResult = add(firstNum, secondNum);
            result += operationResult;
            break;
        case '-': 
            operationResult = subtract(firstNum, secondNum);
            result += operationResult;
            break;
        case '*':
            operationResult = multiply(firstNum, secondNum);
            result += operationResult;
            break;
        case '÷':
            operationResult = divide(firstNum, secondNum);
            result += operationResult;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you forgot to define numberButtons?

Your code shows numberButtons has not been defined, after querySelectorAll number buttons and define them as numberButton, your code should work. See my code snippet.

```js
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operator]');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const equalButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const display = document.querySelector('[data-display]');
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')

function updateDisplay() {

}

function clear() {
    display.textContent = '';
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clear();
})




numberButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click',() => {
    let buttonContent = button.innerText;
    display.textContent = buttonContent;
}))
```

```html
<div class = 'calculator-grid'>
        <div class = 'output'>
            <div class = 'previous-operand'></div>
            <div data-display class = 'display'></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear class = 'span-two grey-button'>AC</button>
        <button data-delete class = 'grey-button'>DEL</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>÷</button>
        <button data-number >7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>*</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>+</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operator class = 'orange-button'>-</button>
        <button data-number class = 'span-two'>0</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-equals class = 'orange-button'>=</button>
    </div>
```